# How to use chrono to time an algorithm with an accumulator timer?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

My code looks something like this:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds total;
for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // some code I want to benchmark
    total += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
    // some code I don't want to account for in my benchmark
}
std::cout << total.count() << std::endl;
```

When I run this code I sometimes get 2, 3 and even 4 as a result. Other times however, I get some random result like 139984111729355 or -4800608627507701400.

Why is that?

Comment: Try initialising your `total` variable

Comment: This sort of benchmarking is a bit 'rough and ready'. If you want something more accurate then Google have release an amazing [Benchmarker Library](https://github.com/google/benchmark), it's really easy to use. Chandler Carruth did a great talk about it that's on YouTube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::chrono::milliseconds total; // (1)
for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // some code I want to benchmark
    total += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
    // some code I don't want to account for in my benchmark
}
std::cout << total.count() << std::endl;
```

This is a perfectly valid pattern, but the problem that your `total` variable at (1) is uninitialised. If you replace it with

```
std::chrono::milliseconds total{};
```

then it should work as intended.